# Electron window handler didn't work with Unity on win10

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10, electron

I try to launch an unity exe in an electron window.

For that:

- I get my window handler ID with `win.getNativeWindowHandle()` from [electron](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#wingetnativewindowhandle).
- I launch my unity exe with :
  `./unity/Child.exe  -parentHWND {window_handler_id} delayed` from [unity doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html).
- On win7 and win8 my window display the unity application, but with win10 I get a blinking window who sometime display my unity exe.

If I launch my unity exe on another window, Firefox for example, it works. But not on Slack or Atom (electron apps).

Do you got an idea ?

Comment: What unity and electron version do you use ?

Comment: Hi, I use electron 1.4.13 and compile my unity exe with version 5.6.1

Comment: 1.4.13 is pretty old. There has been some changes to chrome and electron since it's release. You should try to update electron to 1.6.xx.

Other than that do you run the exec from electron like a launcher? Because i am not sure what you try to archive there ;)

Comment: I will try that. 
Unity can be launch in a specific window if you give it a handler for that.

Comment: With electron 1.6.10, still got the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `win.getNativeWindowHandle()` returns the actual handler ID of your Electron window ?

In this case, did you try to pass this handler to another exe (not the Unity build) ?

Comment: - Yep, I get the same handler with powershell, Get-Process and MainWIndowHandle.I don't have another exe who can get an handler in parameter, except made with Unity